# PHP OOP Database Connection using Seperate Config File with Clasess and functions

Tags: php, oop

The class Dbh is not getting the variables from class ConfigApp.

Everypage.php in the head:

```
<?php include 'config.inc.php'; ?>
```

config.inc.php:

```
<?php
class ConfigApp
{
    const dbhost = "localhost";
    const dbname = "secretdbname";
    const dbuser = "secretdbsuer";
    const dbpass = "secretdbpass";
    const var1 = "something";
    const var2 = "nothingToDoWithDB";
    const var3 = "something else else";
}
?>
```

dbh.class.php:

```
<?php
class Dbh extends ConfigApp{
    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass) {
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpass = $dbpass;
    }

    protected function connect() {
        try {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' .$this->$dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $pdo;
            
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=c1gnsoftdboop' , $dbuser, $dbpass);
            return $dbh;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Database Connection Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>"; 
            die(); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Variables from config.inc.php are not being passed into dbh.classes.php.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Did you `require 'config.inc.php';` in `dbh.class.php` so the `dbh.class.php` actually knows about the ConfigApp class?

Comment: nothing in a code block, AFTER a `return` will get run :)

Comment: There soes not seem to be any point in the `ConfigApp` class at all

Comment: The constructor of the DBH class immediately overwrites all the variables defined in the config class...is that intentional?

Comment: ADyson. Not at all intentional. I removed the constructor class, and still not getting the creds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `ConfigApp` class you've defined [Class Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), not properties. Therefore the syntax to access them is different, as that documentation explains. The pattern is:

```
self::constantname
```

So in your case, you'd need

```
self::dbhost
```

etc.

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/XjCeU

Therefore your code in `connect()` would be

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' .self::dbhost . ';dbname=' . self::dbname;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, self::dbuser, self::dbpass);
```

---

P.S. Everything after `return $pdo;` in the `connect()` function is redundant, since code after a `return` cannot be executed, and in any case you don't need to define the connection twice!

Also, there seems to be no need to pass in new database connection values through the constructor of the `Dbh` class, since you're intending to read them from the `ConfigApp` class constants.

Comment: ADyson, works perfectly! Curious, do you know how to get variables if the vars were:

 class ConfigApp
{
    protected $dbhost = "localhost";
    protected $dbname = "secretdbname";
    protected $dbuser = "secretdbsuer";
    protected $dbpass = "secretdbpass";
}

Comment: Sure...they're just standard class properties so your original code would have worked (except you had one minor typo with a stray extra $). [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) already explains how to access them from within the same class (or in this case, a child class) - not sure if you've had a look at that yet? It's always the sensible place to start investigating. Demo: https://3v4l.org/2unHr

Comment: Again.. Perfect. This is the answer, and with quality. Really like the way you went out of the way to do the demo. Class act.. Thank you!